# Accessing functions from another project in vb2010

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net

I have written a project which has common functions in Visual Basic 2010 i.e. Visual Studio 2010. for e.g.

```
Public Function FlashPolygon(pDisplay As IScreenDisplay, pGeometry As IGeometry)
    Dim pFillSymbol As ISimpleFillSymbol
    Dim pSymbol As ISymbol
    Dim pRGBcolor As IRgbColor

    ' Set the Actions based on Error Mode
    If DEBUG_MODE = 0 Then On Error GoTo FlashPolygon_Error
    If DEBUG_MODE = 2 Then On Error Resume Next

    pFillSymbol = New SimpleFillSymbol
    pFillSymbol.Outline = Nothing

    pRGBcolor = New RgbColor
    pRGBcolor.Green = 128

    pSymbol = pFillSymbol
    pSymbol.ROP2 = esriRasterOpCode.esriROPNotXOrPen

    pDisplay.SetSymbol(pFillSymbol)
    pDisplay.DrawPolygon(pGeometry)
    Sleep(300)
    pDisplay.DrawPolygon(pGeometry)

    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function
```

I want to access this function in a form in another project. I have already added reference to the commonfunctions project. But i am getting error **Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference**.

Can someone help with what mistake I am doing in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error simply means that you have to create a new object of the type the function is in in order to call the function.

```
Dim myClass As New MyClass()
myClass.FlashPolygon(disp, geom)
```

or you can make the function shared.

```
Public Shared Function FlashPolygon(pDisplay As IScreenDisplay, pGeometry As IGeometry)
```